# what is the value for main thread priority?

Tags: java, multithreading

all threads have its priority,so what is the  integer value for main thread?

Comment: It's often a bad idea to start fiddling wth thread priorities as this can lead to starvation.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This code shows you the priority of the main thread:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main( String [] args ) {
        System.out.println( Thread.currentThread().getPriority() );
    }
}
```

The output, and the answer to your question, is **5**.

Comment: Not *all* threads will start with NORM_PRIORITY. Per Thread JavaDocs - "When code running in some thread creates a new Thread object, the new thread has its priority initially set equal to the priority of the creating thread." I thought I should clarify that.

Answer (score 4):

If you still have any doubts, have a look at the JDK's API docs:

From http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#NORM_PRIORITY:

> `NORM_PRIORITY`
>
> `public static final int NORM_PRIORITY`
>
> The default priority that is assigned to a thread.

From http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Thread.NORM_PRIORITY:

> `static final int     NORM_PRIORITY   5`

Answer (score -4):

by default thread value is 6 .......

Comment: Are you by any chance referring to OS priorities instead of JAVA? Have you looked at the other answers?