# Why the out put of below code is Thread[main,5,main]

Tags: java, multithreading, program-entry-point, void

```
public class test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
        System.out.println(t);
    }
}
```

Why the output of above code is - Thread[main,5,main] ?
Please Explain

Comment: because that´s what `Thread#toString` does print.

Comment: The code is trying to get a String representation of the object. That is done by calling the ``toString()`` method of the ``Thread`` class. Take a look at that implementation to find out more.

Comment: @DeepShah [here´s an SO question for this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269807/what-is-the-value-for-main-thread-priority)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because [`thread.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) returns a string representation of this thread, including the thread's name, priority, and thread group.

Answer (score 5):

> Returns a string representation of this thread, including the thread's
>   name, priority, and thread group.

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#toString()

Answer (score 2):

Because of:

```
/**
 * Returns a string representation of this thread, including the
 * thread's name, priority, and thread group.
 *
 * @return  a string representation of this thread.
 */
public String toString() {
    ThreadGroup group = getThreadGroup();
    if (group != null) {
        return "Thread[" + getName() + "," + getPriority() + "," +
                       group.getName() + "]";
    } else {
        return "Thread[" + getName() + "," + getPriority() + "," +
                        "" + "]";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#toString()

```
public String toString()
Returns a string representation of this thread, including the thread's name, priority, and thread group.
```

Here is how we can find the definition:

```
    @FastNative
    public static native Thread currentThread();
```

There is no need to check the native method, just notice that the return type is Thread, so check the Thread.toString definition in Thread.

[image]

Android SDK has the source code.

```
    /**
     * Returns a string representation of this thread, including the
     * thread's name, priority, and thread group.
     *
     * @return  a string representation of this thread.
     */
    public String toString() {
        ThreadGroup group = getThreadGroup();
        if (group != null) {
            return "Thread[" + getName() + "," + getPriority() + "," +
                           group.getName() + "]";
        } else {
            return "Thread[" + getName() + "," + getPriority() + "," +
                            "" + "]";
        }
    }
```